# PyqtGraph ColorBarItem translate and scale

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have heatmap consisting of an ImageItem and a ColorBarItem. But the Color Bar is to small and is positioned at the top left corner of the image. I would like to make it the same height of the image and position it to the right of the image.
How can I change the scale and position of a ColorBarItem?

```
def init_plot(self, max, min):
    self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
    view = self.win.addViewBox()
    view.setAspectLocked(True)
    view.invertY()
    self.pressure_map = PressureMap("foot_preprocess.png", mode=COMPLETE) # class to update the image colors (works fine)
    self.image = pg.ImageItem(axisOrder='row-major')
    self.update() # this changes the image colors (works fine)
    view.addItem(self.image)
    cm = pg.colormap.get('CET-L9')
    lut = cm.getLookupTable(0.0, 1.0)
    self.image.setLookupTable(lut)
    self.image.setLevels([min, max])
    bar = pg.ColorBarItem(values=(min, max), cmap=cm)
    view.addItem(bar)
```

[image: Here is my heatmap]

Comment: For the second time I see using `//` to start a comment in Python. Can you please tell me which IDE do you use? Where does it work?

Comment: @Vitalizzare, It doesn't work I added the comment on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can scale it setting values to width. you can insert to right or bottom using `setImageItem`. Here is the code.

```py
def init_plot(self, max, min):
    self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
    view = self.win.addViewBox()
    view.setAspectLocked(True)
    view.invertY()
    self.pressure_map = PressureMap("foot_preprocess.png", mode=COMPLETE) # class to update the image colors (works fine)
    self.image = pg.ImageItem(axisOrder='row-major')
    self.update() # this changes the image colors (works fine)
    view.addItem(self.image)
    cm = pg.colormap.get('CET-L9')
    lut = cm.getLookupTable(0.0, 1.0)
    self.image.setLookupTable(lut)
    self.image.setLevels([min, max])
    bar = pg.ColorBarItem(values=(min, max),width=30, cmap=cm) #default is 25
    bar.setImageItem( img, insert_in=view)
    view.addItem(bar)
```

I believe this will solve the problem.